# Removing file extension from URI with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to remove the .php extensions from my website's URLs.
I have thus created a `.htaccess` file (created in ASCII text) and moved it to the root folder of my server. It contains the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Unfortunately, it does not work! I've tried different variations of the code but all without success.
I assume that the files is simply ignored...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First two questions to ask: is your Apache server configured to use .htaccess files to override the default server config (AllowOverride all)? And second, is the mod_rewrite extension enabled in Apache?

Comment: What URL are you entering in browser and what error did you get?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the text in .htaccess to,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```